# ¿Cuáles son los otros usos, orígenes y significados de la expresión "Ave María"?

Tags: expresiones, significado

Mientras navegaba por diferentes sitios web de [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/), he encontrado que la expresión *ave maría* tiene los siguientes usos:

> - [Nombre de la oración católica dirigida a la Virgen María.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/995/what-exactly-is-a-hail-mary?rq=1)
> - [En fútbol americano, es *(según entiendo)* un pase largo.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45500/is-the-hail-mary-pass-in-football-offensive-to-catholics)

Otras menciones/usos que he escuchado son:

> - [Nombre de la composición musical *(lied)* hecha por Franz Schubert.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXGgKiYSVuE)
> - Expresión usada en Colombia por los habitantes del departamento de Antioquia y sus alrededores *(aunque no conozco muy bien la definición)*.

Con la anterior información, me pregunto: **¿cuáles son los otros usos, orígenes y significados de la expresión "Ave María"?**

---

*La respuesta aceptada debería (además) exponer las definiciones más elaboradas de las expresiones presentadas en la pregunta.*

Comment: _Eh Ave Maria home_...¿como así que un bogotano no sabe como es que los paisas usamos el Ave Maria.?. Lo usamos todos los días, todo el día pero estuve pensando en como describirlo y no tengo ni idea. Ojala haya otro paisa en este foro que se le ocurra como.

Comment: @DGaleano, usted mismo lo ha dicho: Cito: _`lo usamos todos los días, todo el día pero estuve pensando en como describirlo y no tengo ni idea.`_ eso es lo que quería decir :D Parece que [la respuesta de scubaFun](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15455/5764) puede aplicarse para definir _en parte_ la expresión _Eh ave maría home!..._.

Comment: Si Mauro así es. Uno de los usos parece ser para establecer lo obvio. Otro puede ser para hacer énfasis, como cuando las señoras van a conocer el hijo de la amiga y dicen "Eh Ave María que belleza de muchachito!!" aunque no es obvio que el bebe sea ninguna belleza. :-)

Comment: En Argentina (al menos) es también el nombre de un tipo de fideos para sopa http://www.santamariasa.com.ar/comercio/images/a00028117.jpg http://www.nutrisur1.com/pastas.html

Comment: @leonbloy no lo sabía. He visto los enlaces que presenta en su comentario, pero no encuentro referencias sobre su origen. ¿Se puede asumir que este nombre fue dado como referencia a la Virgen María?

Answer (score 3):

En Puerto Rico, la frase ¡Ave María! se usa para indicarle a otra persona que alguna acción se supone que sea obvia, sin tener una connotación ofensiva (a diferencia de decirle a una persona bruto(a), la cual puede ser ofensiva). Por ejemplo:

> ¡Se supone que supieras que las chinas van en este envase! ¡Ave María!

Es como México se dice "¡Si serás!" (digo que esta frase es de México porque Don Ramón del Chavo del Ocho usaba mucho esa frase)

---

**EDIT:**

Traté de buscar alguna referencia para mi respuesta, pero no encontré nada concreto. Lo mas cercano que encontré fue este [enlace](http://www.wapa.tv/noticias/entretenimiento/asi-se-habla-en-puerto-rico_20131122237932.html/). En él, definen la expression "¡Ave María!" como:

> Expresión de sorpresa, alegría o decepción

Dado que esta definición es muy genérica, la definición presentada inicialmente sería un contexto de "¡Ave María!" en forma de decepción.

(NOTA: el enlace es de la página web del canal de televisión puertorriqueño WAPA).

Comment: En Chile se usa exactamente igual.

Comment: +1 interesante.

Comment: Ah, sí? yo soy de Chile y en mis 4 décadas de vida, jamás escuché esa expresión. Solo la he escuchado en las misas (ave maría purísima, sin pecado concebida) o en la oración del Ave María o en la canción de Schubert. Y sería. Tal vez la gente de más edad la use como expresión :-)

Comment: @jstuardo Se usa mucho, en nuestro país. Qué raro que nunca la hayas escuchado.

Answer (score 2):

En Mexico,

Ave Maria, tambien puede ser interpretado como el nombre de una calle: Avenida Maria, que esta abreviado como Ave. Maria.

Tambien existe la frase: Ave Maria purisima, la cual se usa mayormente por mujeres mayores, y se usa cuando pasa algo que causa asombro.

[image]

No se si esto sea valido para la respuesta pero: 
Recuerdo en la escuela muchos usaban la frase:

> "Ave Maria, dame buena punteria"

la pronunciaban por silabas:

> A-Ve Ma-ri-a da-me bue-na pun-te-ri-a

Y todo con el fin de escojer al azar algo.

Por lo general una opcion, en examenes de opcion multiple. O verdadero y falso.

Tambien se usaba para escoger al azar a alguna persona.

Tiene el mismo significado que la siguiente frase:

> "Pedro picapiedra dice asi yaba daba du sales TU"

Comment: +1 por `ave maría purísima!` también es usado en Colombia de la manera en que lo describe _(aunque no tengo referencias oficiales de que solo se expresen así las mujeres mayores)_. El resto del contenido de su respuesta también es interesante.

Answer (score 0):

Se basa en el en el versículo 28 del capítulo 1 del evangelio de San Lucas. [Cuando el ángel saluda a María](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/San_Lucas_-_Cap%C3%ADtulo_1)

> *28. Y entrando el ángel á donde estaba, dijo, ¡Salve, muy favorecida! el Señor es contigo: bendita tú entre las mujeres.*

Ahora bien, "Ave" no tiene nada que ver con los animales emplumados. En latín, 'ave' se utilizaba por los romanos como saludo (del verbo *avēre*, 'estar bien' con el sentido de 'que estés bien').

Estos versos fueron evolucionando hasta convertirse en la oración llamada "[Avemaría](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avemar%C3%ADa)".

Éste es un fragmento de la oración en Latín:

> ***Ave Maria**,*
>
> *Gratia plena,*
>
> *Dominus Tecum.*

Fuera del mundo religioso, se usa como interjección de asombro o sorpresa:

> "¡Ave maría! Nos vas a matar a todos. Baja la velocidad.".

Se usa de manera similar a

> "¡Dios mío!"

Algunas abuelas solían usar repeticiones del Avemaría para medir el tiempo.

Ejemplo:

> *"Los huevos deben hervirse durante 2 **avemarías**".*

Sobra decir que esta es una forma extremadamente imprecisa de medir el tiempo.

A eso debes sumarle todas las sutilezas de su uso que aparecen en cada país hispano, pero por lo general siempre es lo mismo: Una oración y una interjección de sorpresa.